# Extra page number in Table of Contents without any extra pages, References showing two places

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, thesis

I have the following page, but when I run it, I get a an extra page number after the dedications and List of Tables, not sure why it is doing it. any help would be appreciate it.

```
\documentclass[]{report} 
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[md]{titlesec}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{tocloft} 

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb} 


\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{floatpag}
\floatpagestyle{plain}


\usepackage{listings} 

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage[verbose]{cite}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}


\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{setspace}


\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoF
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoT
\makeatother
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        axis x line=middle,   
        axis y line=middle,   
        axis line style={<->},
        xlabel={$x$},          
        ylabel={$y$},          
    },
    cmhplot/.style={color=black,mark=none,line width=1pt,<->},
    soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*},
    holdot/.style={color=black,fill=white,only marks,mark=*},
}
\tikzset{>=stealth}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{CHAPTER \arabic{chapter}}{0pt}{}{} 
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\bfseries\large} 
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\large}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\large}



\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{1em}     

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{}


\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalsize\normalfont} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}


\cftsetindents{chapter}{.25in}{.25in}
\cftsetindents{section}{.5in}{.25in}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{.75in}{.5in}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{1in}{.5in}

\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip} 
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}


\newenvironment{MyFigure}[1][]{\begin{figure}[#1]\vspace{\baselineskip}}{\vspace{\baselineskip}\end{figure}}

\doublespacing 
\raggedbottom 

\begin{document}
    %DO NOT USE \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
    \large

    \vspace*{2in}
    TITLE\\
    \vspace{2in}
    By\\
    AUTHOR
    \vspace{1in}
    \end{center}
    PERSON1 \hfill PERSON2\\
    PERSON1 \hfill PERSON2\\
    (Chair) \hfill (Committee Member)\\
    \newline\newline
    PERSON3 \\
    PERSON3 \\
    (Committee Member) \\
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
    \begin{center}
    \vspace*{2in}
    TITLE\\
    \vspace{1in}
    By\\~\\
    AUTHOR\\
    \vspace*{1in}
    A Thesis \\~\\~\\~\\
    A UNI\\
    PLACE\\~\\
    DATA\ %month is GRADUATION month;
    \end{center}
    \chapter*{}
    \begin{center}
    \vfill
    Copyright \copyright\ 2017

    \bigskip

    By AUTHOR

    \bigskip

    All Rights Reserved
    \vfill
    \end{center}
    \chapter*{ABSTRACT}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}ABSTRACT}
    \large
    \paragraph{ABSTRACT}

    \chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
        \paragraph{ACKNOLEDGE}
        %\subfile{sections/Acknowledge}

    \chapter*{DEDICATION}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}DEDICATION}
    \paragraph{DEDICATION}
    %\subfile{sections/Dedication}

    \chapter*{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
    \vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter*{LIST OF TABLES}
    \vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \listoftables
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF TABLES}

    \cleardoublepage
    \chapter*{LIST OF FIGURES}
    \vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF FIGURES}
    \cleardoublepage

    \chapter*{LIST OF SYMBOLS}
    %\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF SYMBOLS}
    \paragraph{LOS} 
    %\subfile{sections/Los}

    \chapter*{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
    %\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
    \paragraph{LOA} 
    %\subfile{sections/Loa}


    \cleardoublepage
    \cleardoublepage
    \large
    \clearpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}% Arabic numerals, starting at 1, for the actual document


    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \protect\contentsline{part}{CHAPTER}{}}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\label{Intro}
\section{Background}
\label{Backgrnd}
\paragraph{INTRO}
%\subfile{Sections/Background}

\section{Questions}
\label{Quest}
\paragraph{QUEST}
%\subfile{Sections/quest}

\section{Limitations}
\label{Limit}
\paragraph{LIMIT}
%\subfile{Sections/Limit}

\chapter{RELATED WORKS}
\label{RelWorks}
\paragraph{REL}
%\subfile{Sections/Relworks}

\chapter{METHODOLOGY}
\label{Method}
\paragraph{METHO}
%\subfile{Sections/Methodology}

\chapter{RESULTS}
\label{Result}
\paragraph{RES}
%\subfile{Sections/Result}

\chapter{CONCLUSION}
\label{Conclusion}
\paragraph{CONCLU}
%\subfile{Sections/conclusion}

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}REFERENCES}

\cleardoublepage

\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}
\setstretch{1} %this single spaces within bib entries, but keeps double spaces between entries
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{ref}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{part}{APPENDIX}{}}
\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{APPENDIX \Alph{chapter}}{0pt}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{250pt}{40pt}
\chapter{NON-FINAL APPENDIX TITLE}
\clearpage
First through $n-1^{th}$ appendix goes here
\chapter[\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}FINAL APPENDIX TITLE]{FINAL APPENDIX TITLE}%the last appendix needs to be added strangely
\clearpage
\begin{lstlisting}
LST LISTING IS HELPFUL FOR CODE
\end{lstlisting}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\chapter*{VITA}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{VITA}
\large
\paragraph{}
\end{document}
```

The error:
[image: The PDF]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `tocbibind` causes this. You have so many hand-written `\addcontentsline` that it will cause you presumably no trouble to drop that package altogether: you may not even need add any more `\addcontentsline`, from quick look. But check nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

`\listoftables` and `\listoffigures` are defaults lists that add their own entries to the ToC (by default) Even though you're setting their titles (`\<list>name`) to blank

they still push stuff to the ToC. You can avoid this by inserting the following correction into the ToC:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}% Only print up to \part
}

\chapter*{LIST OF TABLES}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{LIST OF TABLES}
\listoftables

\chapter*{LIST OF FIGURES}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoffigures

\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}% Only print up to \subsection
}
```

[image]

Note that I removed some of the spacing adjustments you included after every `\chapter*` and within the ToC entries. For consistency, I'd suggest changing those things in the preamble as part of how the entries (sectional headers like `\chapter`s or the ToC entries) are set.